# Key considerations for designing Ethernet-based devices

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, communication, ethernet, digital-communications

I am working on a camera board that can send video over Ethernet. I've never designed hardware for any communication protocols other than I2C and SPI and am aware that Ethernet is much more complicated due to its higher speed and connection to external devices.

What are the key considerations when designing an Ethernet device i.e. what topics should I make sure I understand well before starting the design process?

Comment: I'd suggest you make sure you understand the protocols you're going to be using, and what kind of local processing you're having next to the camera.  With my first ethernet board I was surprised how easy the hardware was.  But depending on your currently knowedge of TCP/IP (I assume) and what libraries you're going to use (if any), you might have a lot of work you weren't expecting.

Comment: ... and that's before you even do any video!  The simpler encodings are simple; the higher resolution protocols can be very complex indeed.  Doing for example colour correction or many other operations common to cameras is tricky.  But I imagine you know about video.  If you're goal is "get low resolution video across a wire", that's a different level from "get standards-compliant high-resolution across multicast with lots of options".

Comment: One consideration is the power that is consumed by ethernet. It truly is a power hog, and you should be prepared for that reality.

Comment: I assume that you know that you will need a microcontroller that integrates an Ethernet MAC and PHY, or at least a MAC and an external PHY (which is more typical).

As a way to get started, pick a 10/100 Mbps PHY from any vendor. There should be a "design guide" that will give you lots of information. You can select a different PHY later if you want... but you just need to start somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand transmission lines and differential pairs to some degree, especially if you want to design something that uses gigabit Ethernet. This is for the TX and RX lines. Usually a good ethernet phy will have a good example or evaluation board. And the good ones also have appnotes on how to route and layout the phy.

Most phys have straps (pullup or pulldown resistors) to configure the phy into a certian state on boot. Make sure you follow the proper reset and powerup sequence of the rails clock and reset.

Another thing is picking the interface that you will use to connect to the phy, MII is slowest and easiest to route (25Mhz) but has the most lines. RMII has roughly half the lines and double the speed. RGMII supports gigabit ethernet and is even faster. Make sure both the phy and microcontroller support the interface.